# Can I use Windows Vista (x64) drivers on Windows 7 (x64)?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, windows-vista, 64-bit, netbook

I have a Samsung NC110 Netbook and It has windows 7 on it.

I'm having some issues to find the OEM drivers for windows 7 (64-bit), because this laptop was ment to be used with Windows Vista (64/32). I was able to find drivers for Windows 7 (x64) for most devices, but I wasn't able to find the driver for the IGP.

The provided video driver from samsung, won't install because "This system does not meet the minimum requirements".

I went ahead and looked up on Intel and found two drivers for the IGPU, one is 64 bits for Windows Vista, and the other one is 32 bits for Windows 7. I'm sure that the Windows 7 32bit driver won't work on Windows 7 x64, but I heard that Windows 7 and Vista have some similarities, in the fact that Windows 7 can "import" Windows Vista drivers when updating from Vista to 7, but I'm not completely sure on that. I need to have drivers installed, but I dont want to rely on any "driver_installer.exe"

Comment: It does not seem likely the 32-bit driver would work. Try the 64-bit driver.

Comment: You should use any supported Windows version and that means 10 or newer. Much less drivers to install also.

Comment: Or Linux. Windows 7 is past EOL.4

Comment: Considering it's not possible to use a 32-bit driver on a 64-bit version of Windows, nor is it likely that 64-bit Vista drivers will work on Windows 7, the answer to this question is you shouldn't be using either of the drivers.

Answer (score -2):

You can install 32-bit or 64-bit driver on Windows 7 64-bit. In fact I recommend to install the newer driver.

Comment: Please add sources to back up your claim that you can install 32-bit drivers on a 64-bit Windows O.S.

Comment: @StarCat, my experience. In fact it's well-known fact.

Comment: @PaulK. it's a well known fact that [32-bit driver won't ever run on 64-bit Windows](https://superuser.com/a/87338/241386). Windows kernel doesn't support 32-bit mode at all. Only user processes can be 32-bit. So it's obvious 32-bit driver can't work

Comment: @phuclv, it's well that my HP LJ 1010 did not read that.

Comment: @phuclv, I checked the source link in your comment, it's unavailable I was redirected to MS main page. So your link has not proof.

Comment: @PaulK. you don't know how to read the driver version, or the version was labelled wrong. Lots of driver **installers** are 32-bit so that it can run on any Windows, and then will extract the correct 32 or 64-bit driver inside to install. No major OSes support running 32-bit driver in 64-bit mode. Stop spreading such things if you don't know anything about driver and kernel

Comment: @PaulK. it's easy to find the [archive of the link](https://web.archive.org/web/20130307214829/http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/32-bit-and-64-bit-Windows-frequently-asked-questions)

Comment: Latest MS quote: [***The 64-bit versions of Windows don't provide support for 16-bit binaries or 32-bit drivers.***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/performance/compatibility-limitations-32-bit-programs-64-bit-system). Also [why 32 bit drivers do not work on 64 bit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6307859/995714), https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-run-a-32-bit-driver-on-a-64-bit-Windows-7

Comment: @phuclv, Microsoft does not say it _now_. Stop put archives. Learn is not official infromation from MS.

Comment: @PaulK. then prove that Windows 11 can run 32-bit driver. It has exactly the same kernel as Windows 10 which absolutely doesn't support 32-bit driver in 64-bit kernel just like Windows XP, 7, 8, or Vista. In fact Windows 11 has many 32-bit components removed. Are you just trolling or being stubbornly stupid without technical knowledge?

Comment: @phuclv, question about Windows 7.

Comment: [**No Windows version ever supports 32-bit driver on 64-bit kernel**](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/0f43ede2-3f39-4af8-83b6-cb84255f59b4/can-you-install-32-bit-drivers-on-a-64-bit-windows-7-system?forum=w7itprohardware), not [even Windows 7](https://serverfault.com/a/90933). Either the 32-bit app is a GUI that uses generic built-in 64-bit driver in Windows, or is a generic installer. Period

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20091228050820/http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/32-bit-and-64-bit-Windows-frequently-asked-questions says "Device drivers designed for the 32-bit version of Windows don't work on computers running a 64-bit version of Windows. If you're trying to install a printer or other device that only has 32-bit drivers available, it won't work correctly on a 64-bit version of Windows. "

Comment: Today is 2023 year, you add comments and edit answers to add links from 2009 year. Today MS does not say that! 2016 year: [link]( 
https://superuser.com/questions/87326/is-it-possible-to-use-a-32-bit-driver-on-64-bit-windows-7/87338#comment1511643_87338)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but for some reason drivers exist in 32 and 64 bits. Also, my question wasn't about installing a 32 bit driver of windows 7 on a 64bit version of windows 7. My question is about installing a 64bit version of the Vista driver on a 64 bit version of windows 7